# \WP_User Object | What's the Difference Between {caps} and {allcaps}?

Tags: users, user-roles, user-meta, capabilities

Upon dumping the `\WP_User` object, I've noticed that there are two properties, which are directly related to capabilities for a particular user.

1. `$user_object->caps`
2. `$user_object->allcaps`

I've instantly noticed that there's less array values for `$user_object->caps` than there are in `$user_object->allcaps`. Likely hence the naming convention here.

I currently only observe ONE value under `$user_object->caps`. I also have a custom role assigned to this user. The one value in `$user_object->caps` happens to be the name of my custom user role. However, that very same value is also listed in `$user_object->allcaps`.

1. What's the difference between the two properties `$user_object->caps` and `$user_object->allcaps`?
2. Is there ever a situation where the capabilities listed in `$user_object->caps` **WOULDN'T** be found under `$user_object->allcaps`?
3. Is there any reason I would need to use `$user_object->caps` or can I rely on checking `$user_object->allcaps` for a particular user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Examining the comments for the properties in the [WP_User class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/#comment-2117) reveals that `allcaps` is:

> All capabilities the user has, including individual and role based.

And `caps` is:

> The individual capabilities the user has been given.

But you probably shouldn't be using the properties directly. `WP_User` has a [`has_cap`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/has_cap/) method that should be used instead, as it checks the appropriate properties and runs the result through the relevant filters.